# Firestre Subcollection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add *INSTITUTE NAME* in 1 collection. then in another collection I want to add its *EMAIL ID* of that institute name and email can be multiple.

**What I tried**

```
const registerRef = collection(db, 'instituteList');
  const userRef = collection(db, 'usersList');

    addDoc(registerRef, { institute })
          .then(function (registerRef) {
            addDoc(doc(userRef, registerRef.id), { email })
          })
```

My Problem:-
I am getting this ..
***Document references must have an even number of segments, but.. has 3***

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The firestore data model follows an alternating pattern of collections and documents. You cannot nest a collection under collection, or document under document. That's why document references always an even number of references.

You need to change your database model in order to meet this condition of firestore. Learn more about the firestore data model [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model)

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you have wrong `db.collection("/one" + uid + "/three")` syntax.

Also try Using 2 `addDoc` properties, one for adding institute name and one for emailId so your code will be:

```
 const registerRef = collection(db, 'instituteList');
  const userRef = collection(db, 'usersList');

addDoc(registerRef, {
    instituteName: institute,
  });
  addDoc(userRef, {
    emailId: email,
  });
```